# `set` options in shell

Tags: shell

I often see `set -e` or `set -ex` in dockerfiles and I was wondering what their purpose was. Recently, I've also seen `set -o pipefail`, and I have no idea what it does. I tried `man set` to see if there was any manual description, but there wasn't any and I am resorting to ask here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the full list here:
https://ss64.com/bash/set.html

#### -e

Exit immediately if a simple command exits with a non-zero status, unless the command that fails is part of an until or  while loop, part of an if statement, part of a && or || list, or if the command's return status is being inverted using !.  -o errexit

#### -x

Print a trace of simple commands and their arguments after they are expanded and before they are executed. -o xtrace

#### -o pipefail

If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully.  This option is disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I finally understand their purpose..